# Best practices with OpsWorks Setup Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

yesterday I setup our AWS OpsWorks Bench. We are using a custom cookbook which we are hosting on GitHub. I saw that the setup process failed and had a look in the logs. I saw that the custom cookbook could not be fetched from GitHub because they had server problems. Therefor the setup on the server failed and the process stopped.

Does anyone know if I could handle that sort of failures and restart the setup process till it is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid issues like this is to host your assets on S3. Alternatively you can poll the deployment status to determine if it succeeds or fails and then have some retry logic.